# Redirect to the top from iFrame without JS

Tags: html, iframe

For example there is a link inside of iframe

```
<a href="location-here" target="_top">Click here to continue</a>
```

This link should redirect user to the current window with this addres as far as i know. But it's not working for me in any reason. Do someone know the reason of this behavior? How it should be changed?

**Note:** I can't use the JS.
Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 <a href="location-here" target="_parent">Click here to continue</a>
```

although this might not work aswell due to cross domain issues, I take it the 2 windows are different domains, that is the likely cause, one domaain ( iframe) trying to tell other domain ( main page ) what to do.

Comment: sorry that it was not noticed but i tried it also:(

Comment: try adding `<base target="_parent" />` above the anchor

Comment: base tag didn't help as well

Comment: and it's not cross domain

Comment: and you say you can't use JS, does that include inline JS ? `<a href="location-here" target="_parent" onclick="window.location.href=this.href">Click here to continue</a>

Comment: Oh, i forget about inline:) thanks:) at least i got the error:
`Refused to display 'current-link' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.` i guess it was a reason but error wasn't showed somehow.